# Pandas handling datetime with csv input

Tags: python, pandas

```
           Jan-17   Feb-17   Mar-17
Fixed      20.0      30.5     35.5
Variable   11.5      20.5     30.5
```

I have a csv file with data like this.
This is how I am reading this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col= 0)
df = df.T
```

I wish to extract month out of the index:
but, if I do df.index.month this is not working
even pd.to_datetime() is failing. any way to extract month out of index in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the format your datetime is in:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%b-%d')
```

This will output

```
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-17', '1900-02-17', '1900-03-17'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='d', freq=None)
```

With 1900 as the default year. You can pick and choose the month and day from the `datetime` object with `.month` or `.day` without the `.dt`. For example:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%b-%d').month
```

outputs

```
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name='d')
```

Comment: Ah I see, use `format='%b-%y'` then. Formatting characters can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes